# Android custom title bar, does not work with android:label from manifest

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a custom title bar that I would like to apply to all my activities. I have searched online and found a few ways of doing that however I have ran into a problem.

It seems that despite the fact I have a TextView in my titlebar with id @android:/title, Android will not use the value defined in the manifest in android:label for each activity.

I tried also calling setTitle(R.string.myTitle) but it still will not render it! If I manually put some text in my TextView in the xml it shows up fine.

How can I have a custom title bar that is linked and makes Android use my manifest values for labels? I do not want to lose the setTitle() or the XML attributes functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@android:id/title` instead of `@android:/title`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the original topic. I actually have @android:id/title. Does not work.